# Div animation when tab is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I need to animate a div when a tab is activated.I have this

```
<div class="top">
  <div class="tab_buttons"></div>
</div>

<div class="tabs_container">
  tabs content
</div>

<div class="bottom"></div>
```

On the top div I have the tabs button and when I click on one of them the second div that's is hiddent become active and the bottom div is moved down.Can I do this move with some animation?I have

Answer (score 0):

If you try to adapt container to content height and you are using jquery to trigger your tabs contents and to show and hide you can do:

```
$('.tabcontent1').slideUp(300);
$('.tabcontent2').slideDown(300);
```

for instance and it will adapt the height of the container and push the bottom part accordingly with an animation of 300 milliseconds.